# using a return statement in c++

Tags: c++, return

I am trying to make a function return a the value of dog years. this is what i'm trying to do. It dose not seem to return a value.

```
 int dog_years()
 {
 int addition, dog;
 cin >> dog;
 return 7 * dog;
 }
 int main ()
 {
 int result = dog_years();
 {
```

Comment: please format your code with indentation!

Comment: where would i print result?

Comment: Looks like you may have misunderstood the meaning of `return`. It doesn't mean "print" or "output".

Comment: is there anyway of doing this all inside a module

Comment: I edited my answer. Next time use proper names... look at comment of @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: It *does* return a value. You're just not doing anything with it.

Comment: To see your result write this in main: `cout << dog_years() << endl;`. `result` and `addition` are redundant here.

Comment: @user3495247 is your problem fixed now?

Answer (score 0):

If - as your question states - you want to return a value, you need to assign your return value to a variable:

```
int result = dog_years();
```

after which you can use this variable in you main function for further processing. If you want to "see" your result; you can print it out:

```
cout << results << endl;
```

EDIT:
It seems you just want to "see" your result, without having the return value. in that case:

```
void dog_years()
{
    int dog;
    cin >> dog;
    cout << 7 * dog << endl;
}
```

Comment: The last function return value is still `int`, while it doesn't return anything. Also `addition` is unused.

Comment: the return value of dog_years() should be `void` and addition is redundant here.

Comment: @user3495247 : if my answer helped you; please consider accepting the answer.